# Tap on image to get Input file functionality

Tags: html, css

The code `<input type="file">` will display the following

[image]

But, Instead of displaying the above, I need to display an image, and when the user taps on the image I need to show the option to upload files. Basically, the image will act as the `<input type="file" >`.

My code:

```
  <input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" class="hide"/>
    <img for="imageUpload" src="image URL" id="imagePreview" alt="Preview Image" width="200px"  />
```

Comment: Yup it does. thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)